# Django. How to query an array within a JsonField record?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Django. How to query an array within a JsonField record?

I have a line that contains a JsonField field and inside this jsonfield contains another array field.

How do I query the data and return the line within this array?

Json in database
site paste.ofcode.org/5v3GBex9sWVFBWMWjgbn3Q

```
produto = Produto.objects.filter(pk=pk, labolatorio__historico__items__produto__contains='656aa2b9-9f5e-483b-8182-510bde827d5f').first()
```

I need the result of the index in which the id was compatible

In this case I need this return

```
 {
        "ee": {
                 "ee": 0.1,
                 "values": 0.1
              },
        "insetos": false,
        "produto": "656aa2b9-9f5e-483b-8182-510bde827d5f",
    }
```